# loading image from php to .net application

Tags: php, vb.net, httpwebrequest

I have several images in /public_html/images/ restricted using .htaccess
Meanwhile I created a php file that gets an image.

Example before using POST to change specific ID

```
<?php>
$file = '/home/user/public_html/foodimage/ID-856-front.jpg';
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
print $file;
?>
```

How can I create my Webrequest to pull the image requested from this php file.

```
        Dim request As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
        request.Proxy = Nothing
        request.Method = "POST"
        Dim postData = postvalues
        Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
        Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        dataStream.Close()

        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()

        Dim x As New BitmapImage
        x.StreamSource() = dataStream

        dataStream.Close()
        response.Close()
        Return (x)
```

Please Help. I able to pull off json arrays and strings in a similar function but I can't seem to retrieve images.

Comment: FTP is not an option. I've dealt with too many issues using ftp when not knowing a computers firewall settings.

Comment: Do you get the bytes? Then simply create an Image object and display it (winforms or wpf) or simply save it to the disk. Both options are well-documented and should be easy to find.

Comment: Can't read the length of the datastream so I can't tell if im getting anything in return. I'm using WPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after googling for a couple of hours I was able to get it to work. Heres the code I used to be able to retrieve images from php.

php code

```
<?php>
$photoID = $_POST["uID"];
$file = "/home/username/public_html/imagefolder/ID-$photoID-front.jpg";
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile($file);
exit;
?>
```

vb.net

```
    Public Function getimage(ByVal url As String, ByVal postvalues As String) As BitmapImage
    Dim request As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
    request.Proxy = Nothing
    request.Method = "POST"
    Dim postData = postvalues
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
    Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    dataStream.Close()

    Dim x As New BitmapImage()
    Dim lsResponse As [String] = String.Empty
    Using lxResponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Using reader As New BinaryReader(lxResponse.GetResponseStream())
            Dim lnByte As [Byte]() = reader.ReadBytes(1 * 1024 * 1024 * 10)

            Dim stream As New MemoryStream(lnByte)
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
            x.BeginInit()
            x.StreamSource = stream
            x.EndInit()
        End Using
    End Using

    Return x
End Function
```

Comment: I think you could also determine `Content_length: 1024` from server side, it may help.

`header('Content-length: '.filesize($file));`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in .NET, so I cannot help on that side, but instead of using:

```
print $file;
```

try using readfile() (http://www.php.net/readfile):

```
<?php>
$file = '/home/user/public_html/foodimage/ID-856-front.jpg';
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile($file);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Would like to ask as I'm a bit new to php. I tried print & readfile and it will show the image on the browser. Any info on the difference? Also I don't know how that info will get picked up using webrequest.

Comment: MattMc I would upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputation to do so. I appreciate your help thanks